# Overriding Core Shapes - Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, overriding

I currently have a Content Type called "News" which is very simple (No custom properties etc.). I am trying to style this Content type when it occurs on a page of a specific layout, in this case a "News" page.

So - I have the layout that a News page will inherit from (`Layout-url-News.cshtml`), however I cannot seem to get the Content to display or inherit from a template (I have tried creating alternates such as `Zone-url-News.cshtml` and `Zone-Content-url-News.cshtml`, however both result in having no content at all.)

I had create both of the mentioned alternates by hand, as Designer Tools was unable to generate an alternate (**The relative virtual path 'Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes::Zone' is not allowed here**)

**Basically - I cannot figure out how to style the content found on a specific page, (Title, Tags, Date, Body) as the Content always seems to inheirit from the base shape.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your point is to style content in a zone, u might find it easier to use css.  The layout system makes it really easy to identify the elements your interested in styling by using css selectors.

for example

.aside1.news { ... }

That takes care of 80% of styling needs

Most of the remaining is taken care of by the placement.info file which allows you to indicate which fields and what order for contenttypes and viewstypes (summary and detail)

the remaining needs are address by overriding the contentitem.view.

But you seem to indicate that you want to set the style for a contenttype in a specific zone for a url.  So... You have the same contentType in different zones at the same url?  I cannot imagine what you are doing.  :)

Long and short, it sounds like your focused on the zone but it might be more helpful to focus on the contenttype or better yet, css.  I ran into the same thing with url alternates suggesting alternates that aren't valid.  It seems weird that it suggests zone alternates.  I don't think those those are allowed.

Comment: The CSS wasn't the issue - However I did solve this by doing as you mentioned - making a specific View to style the Content (Content-News.Detail.cshtml) which did exactly as I needed. +1 and Marking as Answered.